# SQL Server Command Metadata - Custom Text for Auditing

Tags: sql-server

Is there a built-in capability to include custom text as metadata to a SQL command?

Use Case:
A manual deployment occurs to a highly-controlled production environment. The person performing the deployment has been assigned a ticket number to authorize the deployment. Is it possible for the person to include the ticket number somehow directly in the script he/she executes such that it is logged on the server as part of the auditable metadata for that command?

We would like to use an auditing tool monthly to dump all DML statements and if the ticket number could be right there next to the command, it would make our lives a lot easier.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL statements don't have meta data attached to them, no. Connections do (such as you can define the connecting application's name in the connection string), however, but that wouldn't serve the purpose you're after. But if you're running a deployment and need to store certain information about it, it seems like that should be within your deployment script.

Comment: @Larnu Of course it does, use `sp_addextendedproperty` etc. See [Working with SQL Server Extended Properties](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5384/working-with-sql-server-extended-properties/)

Comment: DML statements or DDL statements?

Comment: Those are extended properties of an **object** @Charlieface, not a statement. You can't attach meta data to a statement, or batch. Yes, you can add extended properties to an object but not all deployments are DDL related. For example, you might be adding new rows to a lookup/validation table.

Comment: @Larnu Good point, my bad, didn't read the question properly

Comment: @Larnu - is it possible to define custom meta data for a Connection?  That could serve the purpose I'm after.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I did mention DML, but I would need it for any change, including DDL changes.